# How build when you want to use a blog implemented in Gatsby on github and use it on another computer?

Tags: git, gatsby

pushed github files

[image]

Question !

When I had to change my computer, How do using 'git pull'?

Comment: You don't have to push build files to git.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, do you have node installed?
   `node -v`
   If not, [you need to install nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how%20to%20install%20nodejs).
2. Do you have gatsby-cli installed?
   `gatsby -v`
   If not you need to install it.
   `npm install -g gatsby-cli` or
   `yarn global add gatsby-cli`

---

3. Clone your repository from github.
   `git clone https://github.com/my-user-name/my-project.git`
4. Change directory into the newly cloned repository.
   `cd my-project`
5. Install the dependencies
   `yarn` or
   `npm install`
6. Run the project
   `gatsby develop`